# Cypress - Get a string selector from html with space on it

Tags: html, angular, cypress, e2e

I need to retrieve a selector from HTML with a space on it.

```
    <mat-radio-button
        *ngFor="let element of data"
        [attr.data-test]="'radio-buttons-' + element.value">
    </mat-radio-button>
```

element.value got the value of "My pictures"

Cypress cannot find the selector "radio-buttons-my pictures" and do the click.

```
cy.getBySelector('radio-buttons-My pictures').click();
```

Comment: What does the element look like in the DOM, after the variable has been resolved?

Comment: Hello @agoff.  <span style="display: none;">&nbsp;</span>  My pictures - as you can see there is a space on the begging, between words and at the end

Comment: Can you give the full HTML for the element? You don't include the `data-test` attribute in your response.

Comment: The easiest would be to just replace all empty space in element.value with a dash: `element.value = element.value.replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase();` somewhere in ts loop before displaying it in template.

Comment: What is this `cy.getBySelector()` function? How does it handle the arg that is being passed in?

Comment: @DJSDev, cy.getBySelector is a command to get my selectors

Comment: Hello @agoff, thank you !! I will go with these answers. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

As mentionned by Misha Mashina in the comments, you can replace your spaces by other element, like a dash.

On your template, you iterate over an array of objects, so once you get your data, you can just add an attribute to your objects like this :

```js
data = data.map(elem => {
  return {...elem,'data-test-value':elem.value.replace(/\s/g,'-')}
})
```

By doing this, you will have your `value` element with the original value, and the formatted one for your `dataset` attribute.

Comment: Hello @Alexis, thanks for the help. im getting this error , Property 'replace' does not exist on type 'unknown'. can you help me ?

Comment: @HugoSeleiro, if you are sure there is only "string" in your `value` attribute, you can cast it before using `replace`. Like this `(<string>elem.value).replace(/\s/g,'-')`